# Javascript onclick change the variable

Tags: javascript, html, css, variables

I have here a piece of code and into my canvas it shows 10 triangles going into a circle but my problem is that the variable is 10 (var aantal = 10).
I would like a dropdown menu where people can say how many triangles there have to rotate in the canvas.

here is how it looks like now:
http://21248.hosts.ma-cloud.nl/bewijzenmap/periode4/SCT/10x3hoek/index.html

```
      var aantal = 10;
      var triangle = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < aantal; i++){
          triangle[i] = new Triangle;
          triangle[i].xLeft = 20 + 30*i;
          triangle[i].yLeft = 20 + 20*i;

      }

      (function drawFrame () {
         window.requestAnimationFrame(drawFrame, canvas);
         context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

       for (var i = 0; i < aantal; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following html to create a dropdown menu

```
<select id='aantal-select'>
  <option value='10'>10</option>
  <option value='20'>20</option>
  <option value='30'>30</option>
</select>
```

And then the following script to update your `aantal` variable

```
var selectElem = document.getElementById('aantal-select');

selectElem.onchange = function() {
    aantal = selectElem.value;

    var triangle = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < aantal; i++){
    triangle[i] = new Triangle;
        triangle[i].xLeft = 20 + 30*i;
        triangle[i].yLeft = 20 + 20*i;
    }
}
```

Comment: do i need to replace the var = aantal to that piece of javascript?

Comment: Just add the script to your `window.onload` function

Comment: Note that after changing the `aantal` value you have to create the triangles again

Answer (score 0):

Add to your html

```
<select id="select_triangles">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2" selected="selected">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

In your javascript code you could check the value of the selected value like this

```
var e = document.getElementById("select_triangles");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using vanilla javascript (no Jquery/Angular or any other), the easiest will be to change the "aantal" variable to global (remove the "var" in the declaration).
And to change this variable from another event (that the dropdown will initiate).